# js-header and js-footer are not loading drupal 8

Tags: theming

```
portfolio-library:
  version: 1.1
  css:
    theme:
      assets/css/main.css: {}
      #assets/css/font-awesome.min.css: {}
      assets/css/ie9.css: {IE: 'lte IE 9'}
      assets/css/ie8.css: {IE: 'lte IE 8'}

  js-header:
    header: true
    js:
      assets/js/ie/html5shiv.js: {IE: 'lte IE 8'}

  js-footer:
    js:
      assets/js/skel.min.js: {}
      assets/js/ie/respond.min.js: {IE: 'lte IE 8'}
      assets/js/main.js: {}

  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

This is my library file but my js files are not included in my theme can anyone please let me know what is going wrong.

Comment: Most themes will use a global-styling asset library, for the stylesheets (CSS files) that need to be loaded on every page where the theme is active.

Comment: post the exact library file as yml is very picky about the format

Comment: You've just declared these libraries as available within Drupal. Don't you now need to tell your theme to use them? Either in the .info.yml file or in the .theme file? That will make them actually be used

Answer (score 1):

You may be over-complicating this. HTML5 shiv is already in core, so you can just depend on it without any extra work. There's no `js-header` or `js-footer` keys, just use `js` as normal:

```
portfolio-library:
  version: 1.1
  css:
    theme:
      assets/css/main.css: {}
      #assets/css/font-awesome.min.css: {}
      assets/css/ie9.css: {IE: 'lte IE 9'}
      assets/css/ie8.css: {IE: 'lte IE 8'}

  js:
    assets/js/skel.min.js: {}
    assets/js/ie/respond.min.js: {IE: 'lte IE 8'}
    assets/js/main.js: {}

  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/html5shiv
```

If you need your own version for whatever reason, declare the shiv separately:

```
html5shiv:
  header: true
  js:
    assets/js/ie/html5shiv.js: {IE: 'lte IE 8'}
```

and depend on it:

```
portfolio-library:
  ...
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - mytheme/html5shiv
```

Comment: If you're looking for answers on header/footer JS, this is the best version of the information available, and indeed surpasses the d.o docs by a mile.